# making serial connection to my electronic dictionary?

Tags: serial

I've recently found that there's 4 terminals on my old electronic dictionary, each labeled as "/RP TXD RXD GND". The dictionary is more than 5 years old, and runs on 1xAA battery. Is there any chance I could make serial connection to the device with RPi and do something like reprogramming? I'm afraid it's too old and low-powered, but I thought giving it a try could be fun...

Comment: how the "serial connection to my electronic dictionary" become a Raspberry Pi question???

Comment: @lenik It's regarding a connection to the dictionary's serial I/O through the Raspberry Pi GPIO.

Comment: @Jivings I don't see how it's different from "connection of the dictionary to the **generic** serial port to do something like reprogramming".

Comment: @lenik sorry for that. I'm quite new to here. maybe it should have been on Computer Science or StackOverflow? I don't know... I tried CS but it didn't have serial tag.

Comment: I would try google for your dictionary name + "reprogramming" or "serial port". If your dictionary is 5 years old and there are no results on google, most probably nobody could figure out how to do that and/or failed to make it work. Most probably because even if you figure out the correct voltage level (could be 1V, 1.5V, 2.5V, 3V, 3.3V and so on...) and baud rate, this connector is nothing more than debug console that prints some cryptic messages during the boot process. Be careful, though, you may easily burn your dictionary and/or RasPi if you guess the voltage wrong.

Comment: @lenik Questions regarding connecting devices to the Raspberry Pi GPIO serial pins are relevant here and likely to receive a decent answer (as it has done).

Comment: Do you have any documentation regarding it? You could look up the device name to find out how to interface with it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check the voltage on the TXD and RDX lines. The Pi only allows upto 3.3V.

Other than that you can just connect the TX on the Pi to the RX on the dictionary, and vise versa, and the connect the 2 grounds (GND).

I don't think you can reprogram it though. But you might be able to see the boot process. Maybe even add words or something.

Sound like a fun exercise.

Comment: wonder if those lines (RX & TX) are for programming? Would be interesting to play with.